# Instafeed.js not working

Tags: javascript, instafeedjs

I am trying to use Instafeed.js, but my code will not work. I tried the download button at [the InstafeedJS website](http://instafeedjs.com), but it only shows code. I copied that code into a file, saved it as instafeed.min.js, and linked it to my webpage. I followed the steps at the Instafeed website, but it didn't work.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="instafeed.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  var feed = new Instafeed({
    get: 'tagged',
    tagName: 'awesome',
    clientId: 'CLIENT-ID',
    accessToken: 'ACCESS-TOKEN',
    template: '<li><div><a href="{{link}}"><img src="{{image}}" /></a> <h3>{{caption}}</h3></div></li>',
    resolution: 'standard_resolution'
    });
    feed.run();
</script>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="instafeed"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Keep in mind that I do have the correct clientID and accessToken, but I didn't put them in the code above so nobody else can use them.**

Answer (score 2):

Try putting the `<script></script>` tags in the `<body>`, after the `<div id="instafeed"></div>`. The JS may be running before the DOM is loaded.